# Проблема с Android Support Library v4

Tags: android, unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста как убрать эту надпись при старте приложения и при этом сохранить версии библиотек `26.1.0 (Unity)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.arch.core.common-1.0.0
android.arch.lifecycle.common-1.0.0
android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0
```

такие библиотеки попробуй добавить

Comment: Спасибо, надпись исчезла